# Run line after each line in block of code

Tags: python

I am using pygame to create a game, but that shouldn't effect the answer to this question.

At the beginning of the game, all of the images and sounds are loaded, and any objects are created. This can take up to 5 seconds, but as I add more things it might take longer.

I have a loading screen with a small animation that plays while this is all happening, however to update this screen is a little messy (this is just pseudo code):

```
LOAD(IMAGE)
UPDATE(LOADINGSCREEN)
LOAD(IMAGE)
UPDATE(LOADINGSCREEN)
LOAD(IMAGE)
UPDATE(LOADINGSCREEN)
LOAD(IMAGE)
UPDATE(LOADINGSCREEN)
```

As you can see, after everything I load I have to update the loading screen, otherwise the animation will not play.

My question is,is there any way of doing something like this:

```
UPDATE(LOADINGSCREEN){
        LOAD(IMAGE)
        LOAD(IMAGE)
        LOAD(IMAGE)
        LOAD(IMAGE)
        LOAD(IMAGE)}
```

In theory, Python would run a line, and then run the loading screen update, without me having to copy-paste it dozens of times.

Any input would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: This probably depends on how your code is structured. You could make a `LoadAndUpdate` function that does both calls.

Comment: The strictly correct way would probably be to run your UPDATE in a loop on a separate thread (depending on how pygame works / allows you to do that)